# Ubercart: direct access to product/sku page

Tags: ubercart

Drupal 7.32 and Ubercart 3.6

To access a node we use an URL like http://www.example.com/?q=node/17014

I would like been able to access products with
http://www.example.com/?q=sku/12345 or something similar, where 12345 is sku code.

This can make external links to products a lot better!
How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Why not use Pathauto and create a pattern for the product node type that contains the SKU?

Comment: I looked at Pathauto but I think that is a bad way to do this! It's a "brute-force" approach and require continuous update of the alias.

Comment: I wrote a small module to solve my own problem.
This is my first module so use with care!
https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/nicolap/2359567